# Matlab scatter plot set x-axis and y-axis

Tags: matlab, axis, axis-labels, axes

I have an array with two columns (date, value) to plot

```
date = [2002 2003 2004 2005 ....] %sometimes 2003 2005 2006 2009 and so on%

value = [918.5345 918.5361 918.5354 ....]
```

When I plot a scatter as follows:

```
subplot(3,1,1);
hold on;
scatter(date,value,'+');
grid on
xlabel('Time') 
ylabel('Y(m)')
hold off
```

I got the desired graph (but the axes look strange)
[image]

What I want is to set the labels to show the values on y-axis (e.g 918.5345).

ALso, the x-axis to be just the values on (date) ... (e.g 2002 2003 2004 ...) and not 2002.5 2003.5

I use Matlab R2016a

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)?

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of MATLAB the way to get at the tick attribute of a graph was to use the set(gca,'XtickLabel') function. This will "get current axis" and set the x-axis tick labels to the tag you provide. Below, I've set the tag("i") to be an integer requested.

```
     date = [2002 2003 2004 2005]
     value = [918.5345 918.5361 918.5354 918.6354] 

     plot(date, value)

     title('Plot title'); 
     hold on 
     xlabel('X Axis'); 
     ylabel('Y Axis');
     set(gca,'XTick',date) 
     set(gca,'XTickLabel',sprintf('%3.4i|',date))
     set(gca,'YTick',value) 
     set(gca,'YTickLabel',sprintf('%+1.2i|',value))
     hold off
```

To explore more about setting tick labels explore the MATLAB documentation Q/A doc here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103188-how-do-i-format-tick-labels-before-r2016b

Comment: set(gca,'YTick',value)  doesn't work for me but the xTick works perfect. However, I would like just to change the format of the values on Y-axis (e.g to show three digits after decimal)